# Populate the autocomplete jquery vars with sql data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Sorry, i'm noob.
There's a way to populate my .autocomplete dropdown with variables called from my sql table?
If i use `var = ['var1','var2'..` it work. But i need that this variables are called back from my sql table.

Thanks!

```
$( "#product_codes" ).autocomplete({
    source: productvar,
    minLength: 0,
}).focus(function() {
    $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
});
```

Comment: You tagged this with `php`, do you have a php script already that fetches data?

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer!
I'm working on a already existing site, made by ex-colleague.

There's a php page to fetch data from database called back in source:pr.php of .autocomplete.. but i don't like the result.

I’ll explain what I’d like:

I've an input text with .autocomplete jquery but i would to change it in a dropdown list with database table fetched data:

```
<li class="field-container"><label for="pr_code">
                                <span class="field-name"><?php echo $LANG['product_code']; ?></span>
                        
                                <input type="text" value="" id="pr_code" name="pr_code" class="uiStyle text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" onFocus="showHideTip(this);"> *</label>
                            <div id="pr_codeTip" class="hidden formTip">
                                <?php echo $LANG['purchase_pr_code_tip']; ?>                            </div>
                        </li>
```

How can i change the input text in a dropdown list with fetched data?

here the code of pr.php that fetched data for .autocomplete

```
<?php require_once("st_inc/session.php"); ?>
<?php confirm_logged_in(); ?>
<?php require_once("st_inc/connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("st_inc/functions.php"); ?>
<?php
if(!isset($_GET["term"])) { redirect_to("home.php"); }
$q = strtolower($_GET["term"]);
if (!$q) return;

$query = "SELECT * FROM products";
$results = mysql_query($query, $connection);
confirm_query($results);
$items = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) { 
  $items[$row['pr_code']] = $row['pr_name'];
}

/*
$items = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    $items[] = $row['pr_name'];
}
echo json_encode($items);
*/
function array_to_json( $array ){

    if( !is_array( $array ) ){
        return false;
    }

    $associative = count( array_diff( array_keys($array), array_keys( array_keys( $array )) ));
    if( $associative ){

        $construct = array();
        foreach( $array as $key => $value ){

            // We first copy each key/value pair into a staging array,
            // formatting each key and value properly as we go.

            // Format the key:
            if( is_numeric($key) ){
                $key = "key_$key";
            }
            $key = "\"".addslashes($key)."\"";

            // Format the value:
            if( is_array( $value )){
                $value = array_to_json( $value );
            } else if( !is_numeric( $value ) || is_string( $value ) ){
                $value = "\"".addslashes($value)."\"";
            }

            // Add to staging array:
            $construct[] = "$key: $value";
        }

        // Then we collapse the staging array into the JSON form:
        $result = "{ " . implode( ", ", $construct ) . " }";

    } else { // If the array is a vector (not associative):

        $construct = array();
        foreach( $array as $value ){

            // Format the value:
            if( is_array( $value )){
                $value = array_to_json( $value );
            } else if( !is_numeric( $value ) || is_string( $value ) ){
                $value = "'".addslashes($value)."'";
            }

            // Add to staging array:
            $construct[] = $value;
        }

        // Then we collapse the staging array into the JSON form:
        $result = "[ " . implode( ", ", $construct ) . " ]";
    }

    return $result;
}

$result = array();
foreach ($items as $key=>$value) {
    if (strpos(strtolower($key), $q) !== false) {
        array_push($result, array("id"=>$value, "label"=>$key, "value" => strip_tags($key)));
    }
    if (count($result) > 11)
        break;
}
echo array_to_json($result);

?>
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i solved it with this:

```
<li class="field-container"><label for="pr_code">
                                <span class="field-name"><?php echo $LANG['product_code']; ?></span>
                        
                                <select name="pr_code" id="pr_code" class="uiStyle text ui-widget-content"> 
                                 <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","***","","***");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();}
    $sql="SELECT * FROM products";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {    
    echo '<option value='.$row['pr_code'].'>'.$row['pr_code'].'</option>';
      }
?>;
</select>
```

thanks!